# Exodus wallet on USB key

Tags: bitcoin, wallet

I wonder if it's possible to save private data from Exodus wallet to USB storage so it can be accessed by Exodus and also from internet only when plugged in.

Has anybody managed to do so on linux ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps  [bitcoin.se] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about crypto currencies, not programming

Answer (score 0):

Exodus USB based wallet or software that can convert any USB is coming soon or is planned based on Exodus's road map. 
Here is the link:
http://support.exodus.io/article/96-exodus-wallet-roadmap

Having a Exodus USB based wallet and a Exodus Mobile App is much needed.